# how can i use for loop in this situation?

Tags: matlab

```
X=randi([1,5],3,1); 
Y=randi([1,5],3,1); 

for i=1:3; 
    Xnew(i)=[X(i,1)+.6];
    Xn=Xnew'; 
    Ynew(i)=[Y(i,1)+.4];
    Yn=Ynew'; 
end 

plot(Xn,Yn,'kd'); 
grid on;
hold on; 
D2X=randi([1,5],3,1); 
D2Y=randi([1,5],3,1); 
plot(D2X,D2Y,'ro');
hold off; 
axis([1,50,1,50]);
```

my problem is like on the first day source is generating three particles then these three particles move with the groundwater velocity, on the second day three particles again are generated by the source, on the third day again three particles by source and former particles will be moving with the groundwater velocity, source generates particles in a definite range only lets say (0-5).and this will continue for 365 days.

Comment: it's not getting formatted

Comment: An edit is in the review queue. Your question as stands needs a lot more information before we can answer it. You talk about days, sources, velocity, and particles without introducing your problem.

Comment: source is nothing just 3 particle generater , velocity is  0.6 m/day in x direction and 0.4m/d in y direction and particles is just that i have written 3 in the code we have to randomly locate these particles so i have to use randi , days is it'll continue upto 365 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do. Please clarify your question if I misunderstand.

```
xyRange=[1,5];      %// Starting xy range of particles
numP=3;             %// Number of particles generated each day
vx=0.6; vy=0.4;     %// x and y velocity
numDays=365;        %// Number of days to generate particles

X=[]; Y=[];         %// Vectors start out empty

for day=1:numDays
   %// Generate numP particles and add to end of vectors X and Y
   X=[X;randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 
   Y=[Y;randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 

   %// Move all the particles
   X=X+vx;
   Y=Y+vy;
end
```

This version moves the particles on the day they were generated. If you want to only start moving the particles on the day after they were generated, you can change things around a bit:

```
xyRange=[1,5];      %// Starting xy range of particles
numP=3;             %// Number of particles generated each day
vx=0.6; vy=0.4;     %// x and y velocity
numDays=365;        %// Number of days to generate particles

%// Generate first numP particles
X=[randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 
Y=[randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 

for day=2:numDays    %// Note we've already done Day 1
   %// Move all pre-existing particles
   X=X+vx;
   Y=Y+vy;

   %// Generate numP particles and add to end of vectors X and Y
   X=[X;randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 
   Y=[Y;randi(xyRange,numP,1)]; 
end
```

At the end of either version, the first particles generated will be at `X(1:3),Y(1:3)` and the last particles generated will be at `X(end-2:end),Y(end-2:end)`.

I'm not sure whether you want to plot each day or only at the end of the year, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. but yeah we have to keep days as variable because at any time we should be able to plot it and another thing is final position will be equal to initial position plus velocity*time. and this time will be like..suppose we are assuming 1 year to be the time period then particle that were generated on 1st day will move for 364 days(t-1) and the particles that was generated on the second day will move for 363 days like(t-2), particles that were generated on third day will move for 362 days....and so on

Comment: okay in this code that you wrote down we can change the condition of for loop for finding out at different number of days because it is having a one day time difference.

Comment: suppose we have done for 50 days (i.e. for day= 1:50) then when we plot it like plot (X,Y,'kd'); axis([1,50,1,50]); grid on; the how can we calculate number of particles in each grid, i mean what will be the code for it i tried function box = coord(X,Y)
for j = floor(X/5)+1;
    k = floor(Y/5);
    box = k*10+j;
 end

Comment: @Snehaagrawal I've added a second version of the code that hopefully fixes your one day time difference.

Comment: @Snehaagrawal Incidentally, since the acceleration is constant, if you only want the results after `numDays` days and you don't need the intermediate results, we can perform the calculations without a loop.

Comment: actually that can be fixed in the previous code itself. but i wondering if u can help in counting the number of particle in each grid also whatever i tried that was telling that how which particle is in which grid box but i have to count number of particles in each gri..so i don't knw how to do it ?

Comment: @Snehaagrawal "actually that can be fixed in the previous code itself." Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, you can't. You will be moving new particles on the day they are generated. As for your "grid box" question, again, I don't understand what you're asking, but that should be a new question with a clear explanation of the desired behavior.

Comment: regarding that second question when u run this programme u'll get some plot i want to count number of particles in each grid box,,,,, for clearly understanding take number of days to be 5 or 10 then plot it then how to count numer of particles in each grid box

Comment: @Snehaagrawal Don't keep adding to the comments. If you have updates for **this** question, edit the question and clarify. If you have a **second** question then you should post another question.